# Parsing a nested sentence and related with them PHP

Tags: php, regex, parsing, string-parsing

I am doing a parsing operation on some data. I am taking this line from database. 
In this line : 
 Between `[ ]` this things are the author names. There can be author more than one. After that `[ ]`, to the end of the first `,` there is the university of the authors.

**Example Line**

`[Joseph, Susan; Forsythe, Stephen J.] Nottingham Trent Univ, Pathogen Res Ctr, Sch Sci & Technol, Nottingham NG11 8NS, England. %#[Cetinkaya, Esin; Ayhan, Kamuran] Oxford Univ, Fac Engn, Dept Food Engn,06110 8NS, England.`

For example for this line, the expected output should be:

`Susan Joseph : Nottingham Trent Univ`
`Stephen J. Forsythe : Nottingham Trent Univ`
`Esin Cetinkaya : Oxford Univ`
`Kamuran Ayhan : Oxford Univ`

**Here is what i done right now :**

[image]

**My Code**

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo "<br>";
      echo $row['Correspounding_Author'] ;
      echo "<br>";
      $pattern = '~(?<=\[|\G;)([^,]+),([^;\]]+)~';
      if (preg_match_all($pattern, $row['Correspounding_Author'], $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
         print_r(array_map(function($match) {
             return sprintf('%s %s', ltrim($match[2]), ltrim($match[1]));
        }, $matches));

      }
}
```

`This code is taking the authors from that line but i cannot related them with their universities`

Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this works:

```
$teststring = '[Joseph, Susan; Forsythe, Stephen J.] Nottingham Trent Univ, Pathogen Res Ctr, Sch Sci & Technol, Nottingham NG11 8NS, England. %#[Cetinkaya, Esin; Ayhan, Kamuran] Oxford Univ, Fac Engn, Dept Food Engn,06110 8NS, England.';

preg_match_all('/\[([^\]]+)]([^,]+)/', $teststring, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $authors = explode(";", $match[1]);
    foreach ($authors as $author) {
        echo preg_replace("/([^,]+),\s?(.*)/", "$2 $1", $author)." : ".$match[2]."<br />";
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
Susan Joseph : Nottingham Trent Univ
Stephen J. Forsythe : Nottingham Trent Univ
Esin Cetinkaya : Oxford Univ
Kamuran Ayhan : Oxford Univ
```

Working code example:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1f9b68427fa71f74c3e6b775a3dbc3202f2c0d4a